# sudo as another user with password from stdin

Tags: shell, passwords, aix, sudo

I am attempting to use `sudo` check to see if the password for the user is set to a standard password.

I have read that you can use the `-S` option to receive input from `stdin`

> -S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
>                   the standard input instead of the terminal device.

but when i run `echo 'password' | sudo -S -u user command`

it returns:

```
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

Could somebody tell me what is off with this script?

**Note:** I have tried other methods to check the password but I am having a hard time finding a solution because I do not have: root access, a c compiler, or the availability to install programs like expect

Comment: It works for me. Perhaps it's just telling you that that's not the user's password. Incidentally, if you don't have root access, why are you looking at other users' passwords? If there's a security problem, bring it up with the admin(s) responsible for the system.

Answer (score 4):

Does your password end in a newline?  Try:

```
printf password
```

or

```
echo -n password
```

Comment: ooh good call. Tried that....interestingly enough it loops three times now ` Password: Sorry, try again. sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts`

Answer (score 1):

Sudo is not expecting the password of the specified user, rather the password of the user calling "sudo":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo